# Computing expected loss

Tags: distributions, finance

I have three options like $A_{1}\leq A_{2}\leq A_{3}$. If I choose the higher value $A_{3}$ , I have more risk to loose. Let me make it clear , if I choose first the expected loss will be 1 , for the second 3 and for the third 5. In general ,technicaly speaking,  how can I calculate this expected values of loss for each options ? I calculate the probability of P(X<$A_{1}$) where X is a random variable. What should I do next ?

Thank you

Comment: The two most popular risk measures in this context are Value at Risk (VaR) and Expected Shortfall. The first one is related to the probability calculation you described.

Comment: Yes , I know those concepts but they need more parameters to compute . In my case, basically I have to compute expected loss ? Let's if P(X$\leq $A_{1}$) is 0,78 , what is the expected loss ?